# Yet Another Question Closed Don't Know Why - please tell me, don't keep me in the darkness

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Here is the question: [Do you see an use for "Spreadsheet programming"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61394/do-you-see-an-use-for-spreadsheet-programming/188854#188854)

Short summary: spreadsheets should be translated into standalone apps, is there any example, is it a good idea, what's your opinion, experience?

Yes, it's not a question like "what's the name of string replace function in PHP?" (this is a daily question from Stack Overflow and *never* gets closed), instead, it's an excellent idea, which is "not in the air" like big data or whatsoever, but if we discuss this, the world should go further. I think.

I can understand if it gets closed on Stack Overflow, but this is the *Programmers* site, where dudes can come out with new ideas, ask others wheter they tried or not or will it blend.

Point out please that I'm wrong, **but**, with the same movement, send me to the appropriate Stack Exchange site, where programmers can discuss about theoretical issues, plans, architectures. I'm looking for something just like code reviews, but only with ideas, concepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites are for answering specific questions that can be backed up with some combination of facts and experiences, not discussing ideas. Asking people for their opinions or thoughts on a subject or carrying out an extended discussion.

The question you linked to is very clearly a poll. It's not about solving a problem or understanding a topic:

> I am interested in knowing whether you have experienced using the technique and what for.

That right there makes the question a bad fit everywhere on the network.

Every site does have a chat room. People with 100 reputation on a site can create chat rooms for discussion of a particular topic. Anyone with 20 reputation can participate in any of the public chat rooms. Discussion should either happen in these chat rooms or in a more suitable format, such as a discussion forum.

Comment: "I am interested in knowing whether you have experienced using the technique and what for" - yes, this is a question of kind, answer accepted. But people, who have done their homework, and have no known bugs at all, and have some spare time, often discuss similar topics. If you say that StackExchange is not a place for it, I can accept it, but I think it's a mistake.